# Debugging a Hotspot VM in Netbeans

Tags: debugging, netbeans, jvm

I built a (customized) 1.8 HotSpot VM in Netbeans 7.2 using GDB 7.4 which works for executing Java programs. I want to debug a SIGSEGV that the program produces by calling a native function called by JNI that corrupts an object header.

However, I have some problems debugging the HotSpot VM: I have several breakpoints before the call to the main function in java.c. Sometimes, they trigger and sometimes the main function executes without all the breakpoints halting before. The most far I can get is

```
/* Invoke main method. */
(*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, mainClass, mainID, mainArgs);
```

After that, a step-in runs through the whole Java program, eventually triggering the SIGSEGV. The call is leading to the JNI API so I included the "hotspot/src/share/vm/prims" directory to the source dirs in the debug section. However, I could not see any effect. Does anybody have an idea how I can step into the C++ method calling the Java main method?

When the SIGSEGV causes the Netbeans debug view to stop, the call stack shows the expected call stack. However, instead of the C++ code it just shows assembler code while displaying the names of the C++ classes. The initial caller is "?? ()". Is there some way to see the C++ code or do I have to manually map the assembler code to the C++ code? I read a great [article by Volker Simonis](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2008/01/24/hotspot-development-linux-netbeans-part-2) where he describes that such unknown frames relate to generated code. However, I'm still puzzled that the consecutive caller frames show class and method names. Is it a problem with source lookup or simply relates to the first unknown frame?

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile hotspot in `debug` mode, i. e. `make all_debug`? If hotspot is optimised than code may be run in different order than it's in source file, and some symbols can be stripped out, preventing debugger to give you meaningful info, or setting a breakpoint.